# Showing that if $K$ is an infinite field, then the morphism $\phi : K[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to K$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an infinite field, then I’d like to show that the morphism $\phi : K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \rightarrow K$ such that $ P \mapsto ev(P)$ (mapping polynomials to polynomial functions) is injective. It is suggested [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3594169/328767) to do this by induction, but I’m stuck in $n=1$:

If $n=1$, $P\in \ker(\phi)$ iff $P(k)=0$ ($k\in K$) iff $x_1-k$ divides $P(x_1)$, but I don’t see how this implies that $P=0$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The morphism should be $\phi : K [x_1, \dots , x_n] \to K^{(K^n)}$, not $\phi : K [x_1, \dots , x_n] \to K$ (the latter is not injective indeed). For $n=1$ you have that a nonzero polynomial has only finitely many zeroes, hence the kernel has only the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Crostul Just making sure, what do you mean by the notation $K^{(K^n)}$ exactly?

Comment: @Crostul “you have that a nonzero polynomial has only finitely many zeroes…” Oh, and then you’d have a contradiction because $k$ could be any element of $K$ and $K$ is an infinite field?

Comment: You got it. Here $K^{(K^n)}$ denotes the set of functions $K^n \to K$, which is a $K$-vector space.

Comment: @Crostul All is clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The base case comes from the following well known fact: if $P, Q$ are polynomials of degree at most $m$, and $P(a)=Q(a)$ for $m+1$ different points $a$, then $P=Q$. You should try to prove this (hint: consider the polynomial $R = P - Q$).